# How can I make the animation to rotate a widget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, rotation, qwidget, qpropertyanimation

I want to convert the anim_2 into a rotation but I don't know how or even if it's possible. I tried to use the QPropertyAnimation with (b"angle") but it don't do nothing. Any help or idea? Thanks!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.child = QWidget(self)
        self.child.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;border-radius:15px;")
        self.child.resize(100, 100)
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.child, b"pos")
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(200, 200))
        self.anim.setDuration(1500)
        self.anim_2 = QPropertyAnimation(self.child, b"angle")
        self.anim_2.setStartValue(90)
        self.anim_2.setEndValue(270)
        self.anim_2.setDuration(2000)
        self.anim_2.setLoopCount(-1)
        self.anim_group = QSequentialAnimationGroup()
        self.anim_group.addAnimation(self.anim)
        self.anim_group.addAnimation(self.anim_2)
        self.anim_group.start()


app=QApplication([])        

MW=Window()
MW.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Property animations work only with *existing* Qt properties. Qt widgets don't support rotation, and `angle` is not an existing property anyway. To check the properties of objects, always look for the [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties) section in the documentation (including the inherited classes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know any kind of animation to perform a rotation without a QGraphycsScene? Because I already have an screen where I want to rotate the widget. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you've not understood the point: there is not an "animation that rotates" or an "animation that scales". Qt animation is a framework that allows interpolation of values.  The basic animation (QVariantAnimation) provides interpolation of types that allow that (for instance: integer or floating numbers, rectangles, colors). QPropertyAnimation allows to automatically update *properties* of a Qt object, but the object must *have* that property: there is no way to rotate a widget with an animation, because as said, widgets do ***not*** support rotation.

Comment: Oh fine, thanks. Now I've understood how it works...